# Assigning Public IPs to two Routers

Tags: networking, router, ip

I was hoping someone can help me with an issue I have been having.

Here is our old setup:

Leased line connection > LL "modem" that has two Ethernet interfaces > Two routers that are manually assigned their public IPs.

New setup:

New fiber connection > Fiber "modem" that has one Ethernet interface > ? > Two routers.

Here is where the problem begins. The new ISP requires us to use PPPOE to log in and will only allow one instance. So I can't just pop a switch and add PPPOE dialers to both routers.

We have a /29 subnet with access to 6 public IPs and the two routers need to be assigned a public IP.

I have a Cisco 1841 router I can use to remedy this issue.

Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That's not something you can fix. Speak to your ISP.

Comment: It could be that the whole /29 is routed to the PPPoE client and some "proxy ARP" could route it through towards the 2nd router. Still, speaking to ISP would be the best option.